# How to show the tree of a root folder only for the first child level, and then show for just one of the children the second child level as well?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, command-line-arguments, tree

Setting down a guide about a repository, it should help the reader to look through folders and files in only that sub-folder which makes the core of the task at hand, and without any sub-sub-folders. And it would then help as well to see by the same time and in the same tree the embedding of this sub-folder into the full repository's tree of folders and files on level 1, that is, anything right below the root, but not more.

Workaround for now is to paste one tree into the other, with tab for the right indent:

- the whole list of folders and files of the root folder
- only one nested folder (`scripts`) with all of the folders and files of the first children of that folder, thus, no grandchildren level.

`$ tree -La 1`

and

`$ tree ./scripts -La 1`

```shell
$ tree -La 1
.
├── application
...
├── scripts
    $ tree ./scripts -La 1
    ./scripts
    ├── crontab
    ...
...
└── VERSION
```

Is there a way to do this only with the command line? So that the output is right away:

```bash
.
├── application
...
├── scripts
    ├── crontab
    some_file1
    ...
...
└── VERSION
some_file2
```

This can be answered for both Windows and Linux, shell script allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for Linux.

If your `tree` supports `--fromfile` then you can read from `find`. [There are quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891954/10765659) and I'm going to fight one of them with `sed`. I hope your `find` supports `-maxdepth`. GNU `find` does support it, I assume you can use GNU `find`.

```
find . ./scripts -maxdepth 1 | sed 's|^./||' | tree --fromfile .
```

`./scripts` will appear twice in the output from `find`, but `tree` should compact this into one.

It's trivial to add more paths of interest. Example:

```
(cd / && find . ./etc ./var/log -maxdepth 1 | sed 's|^./||' | tree --fromfile .)
```

My `tree` colorizes its output to the terminal, directories are blue. `tree --fromfile` recognizes directories by trailing slashes. `find` does not print trailing slashes, unless we explicitly ask it to. Our example fixed:

```
(cd / && find . ./etc ./var/log -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%p/\n' -o -print \
| sed 's|^./||' | tree --fromfile .)
```

Comment: Yes, took the coloured tree from the last code line in your answer and put in the one scripts folder again: `find . ./scripts -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%p/\n' -o -print | sed 's|^./||' | tree --fromfile .`.

Comment: I asked a follow-up question on how to keep the colours when copying from the Terminal at [How to copy the "tree" command output with the red/blue/white colours from Terminal to system on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1743258/how-to-copy-the-tree-command-output-with-the-red-blue-white-colours-from-termi)