# How to copy the "tree" command output from Linux Terminal without losing the red/blue/white colours of the folder/file tree?

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, copy, tree

When copying the output of the "tree" command from the Terminal, the colours that were shown in the terminal get lost, whether I put it here or in a Google Drive Doc.

Example:

```shell
tree /var/log/apt -La 1
/var/log/apt
├── eipp.log.xz
├── history.log
├── history.log.1.gz
├── history.log.2.gz
├── term.log
├── term.log.1.gz
└── term.log.2.gz
```

Though in Terminal, it there is red, blue, and white:

[image]

My aim is to paste this into a Google Drive Doc (that is, in a Browser  web application) on Linux without losing the colours, and I guess that this loss of does not depend on the Google Drive Doc, but on the Terminal, I seem to lose the colour already when copying. The question of how to copy this to Google Docs is at [How to put coloured HTML text in the way that it is shown in a browser into Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/166721/how-to-put-coloured-html-text-in-the-way-that-it-is-shown-in-a-browser-into-goog) on Web Applications Stack Exchange.

How to keep the colours when copying from Terminal into a file that is not in Terminal?

Comment: You can't really, coloring as achieved using ANSI escape sequences so you'd have redirect output of tree somewhere to the file and get a program that can convert them into Google Drive Doc format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create HTML output that can be displayed in a browser, the
[tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree)
command could have this syntax :

```
tree -H \\localhost -T title -C -o test.html
```

The options used are :

> **-H baseHREF**
>
> Turn on HTML output, including HTTP references. Useful for ftp sites.
> baseHREF gives the base ftp location when using HTML output. That is,
> the local directory may be '/local/ftp/pub', but it must be referenced
> as 'ftp://hostname.organization.domain/pub' (baseHREF should be
> 'ftp://hostname.organization.domain'). Hint: don't use ANSI lines with
> this option, and don't give more than one directory in the directory
> list. If you wish to use colors via CCS stylesheet, use the -C option
> in addition to this option to force color output.
>
> **-T title**
>
> ```
> Sets the title and H1 header string in HTML output mode.
> ```
>
> **-o filename**
>
> ```
> Send output to filename.
> ```
>
> **-C**
>
> Turn colorization on always, using built-in color defaults if the
> LS_COLORS environment variable is not set. Useful to colorize output
> to a pipe.

Comment: In the example, it would be `tree /var/log/apt -La 1 -H var/log/apt -T test_title -C -o test.html` with `var/log/apt` as the root that is shown at the top of the tree, and the file can then be found in the same folder in which the command was run. Works, I get html in the output file, and it can be shown in the browser with the colours blue and black.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the specific Terminal...

- *Some* terminal emulators support copying the output as HTML (or RTF) – not just "text containing HTML tags" but as actual HTML-typed clipboard content – which can then be pasted into most word processors and be recognized as formatted text.

  For example, in GNOME Terminal you can shift-right-click and select "Copy as HTML". I think Windows Terminal also has a similar option that must be enabled through its settings page first.

...and depends on where you're pasting it.

- Some text fields support formatted content, others don't. For example, this site uses a plain-text input widget, so even *if* your clipboard contains formatted text, the web browser always requests the "text/plain" type when pasting.

  Google Docs uses an entirely custom input widget, but you can paste "text/html" clipboard data into it and it will in fact show up as formatted text.

Comment: Right, it does not paste as such into Google Docs. That was not the question, though, since I need to copy the colours in the first place if I want to get the chance to paste it as such again. I opened a question at Web Applications Stack Exchange with: [How to put coloured HTML text in the way that it is shown in a browser into Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/166721/how-to-put-coloured-html-text-in-the-way-that-it-is-shown-in-a-browser-into-goog).